# Fast Fourier Transform Output Manipulation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, audio, fft, wav, equalizer

I am building a visual equalizer for audio and am confused what the output to my FFT is. My end goal is to send a simplified array of 6 numbers (1 bass, 4 mid-tones, and 1 treble) to an Arduino equipped with bluetooth.  The numbers will denote how many LEDs to light up in each column (1 column for bass, 1 column for treble, etc).

The first step is to change an audio signal into numerical representations.
In order to do that I want to combine certain frequencies into discrete buckets at regular time intervals, i.e. one for Bass that's 60 to 250 Hz.

I've obtained a 300Hz wav file that I am trying to deconvolute using the ruby `FFTW3` gem.  I would expect one sine wave that completes 300 periods over the course of a 1 second sample. When I pass in a 1s sample of a 300 Hz tone, the `fft.length = 1024` and `fft[0] = 22528`.

I have been using these conversations [Audio Equalizer in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528293/audio-equalizer-in-ruby), and [Extract Fast Fourier Transform data from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031544/extract-fast-fourier-transform-data-from-file#comment21153172_15035230) as my main points of reference as the documentation for the ruby gem is confusing.

Here's my code:

```
require "ruby-audio"
require "fftw3"
require "narray"

# Audio sample rate and block size:
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100
# break the audio into chunks (called windows, or frames)
# pass them sequentially to the FFT.
# gives a frequency profile that changes over time
# e.g. 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, etc..
WINDOW = 2048
# samplerate/window => 44100/2048 = 10.7
# Updates about 11 times/second
# RESOLUTION = (1.0*SAMPLE_RATE/WINDOW)

filename = ARGV[0]

wave = Array.new # length is window size/2
fft = Array.new(WINDOW/2,[])

begin
  # extracting audio from wav with ruby-audio
  buf = RubyAudio::Buffer.float(WINDOW)
  RubyAudio::Sound.open(filename) do |snd|
    while snd.read(buf) != 0
      wave.concat(buf.to_a)
      na = NArray.to_na(buf.to_a)
      fft_slice = FFTW3.fft(na).to_a[0, WINDOW/2]\
      # na = array to be transformed
      j=0
      fft_slice.each do |x|
        # getting the real part of the complex number
        x = x.abs
        fft[j] << x; j+=1
      end
    end
  end

rescue => err
    # log.error "error reading audio file: " + err
    puts 'There was an error, exiting!'
    exit
end
```

Are the inner-most arrays denoting frequencies, and the outer representing time passing, or is it the other way around.  How do I know which array index represents a specific frequency?

I am unsure of how to test this to see if it has accurately created the proper frequency. Is there a good way to look at the data that I've missed, visually or otherwise?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: I don' t know ruby so could you explain what `fft[j] << x` does?

Comment: That part of the function is taking the value x and putting it into the fft array at position j. It then increments j so the next value will be at the next index.

Comment: So it's the same as a = for assignment?

Comment: Similar, but `fft[j] << x` is how to assign things into arrays.